# Identify the smallest $c$ such that $P(|X_n| \ge c \sqrt{\ln n} \text{ i.o.}) = 0$ for normally distributed $X_n$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, analysis, probability-theory

The problem is to show that $P(|X_n| \ge c \sqrt{\ln n}\text{ i.o.}) = 0$ for standard normal $X_n$ that are not necessarily independent. Also, identify the smallest such $c$.

I am thinking that the Borel-Cantelli lemmas are the way to go here but I can't figure out how to get a bound on this probability. Chebychev's inequality does not work.  I suppose I will need to use Markov's inequality and the 4th moment.  But even in that case how would I find the smallest $c$?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Borel-Cantelli indeed. Hint: when $x\to+\infty$, $1-\Phi(x)\approx\exp(-x^2/2)$, in a loose sense which can be made precise. // But, if every $X_n$ is **standard** normal (please make clear whether this hypothesis holds), there is no *smallest* $c$ such that this holds.

Comment: Does "i.o." mean "infinitely often"?

Comment: Actually when my question was edited the "ln" under the sqrt was removed but it should be there.

Comment: Then you need to find a simple equivalent of $P(|X|\geqslant c\sqrt{\log n})$ when $n\to\infty$, for $X$ standard normal. Did you reach that?

Comment: Any luck with the hints above?